# What are all the catalogs that RDBMS have to implement to be ANSI compliant?

Tags: information-schema, metadata, sql-standard, catalogs

My goal is to be able to go into any environment, and immediately get a general idea of what is going on in a database server. I know most RDBMS implement INFORMATION_SCHEMA, which has a lot of useful information in it. 
Is this the only vendor neutral catalog, or are there other helpful catalogs that return system metadata?